# How to join a Skirmish in Neverwinter Online?

Tags: neverwinter

Longtime MMORPG player, first time Neverwinter player, but having a lot of trouble completing the "[Driving Back the Orcs](https://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Driving_Back_the_Orcs_(Skirmish))" quest in Neverwinter Online. The linked wiki doesn't help much, and searching leads to only [one relevant result at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Neverwinter/comments/8v19zf/how_do_i_start_orc_assault_in_the_tower_district/) that says:

> Go to queue’s and queue for it. It’s a skirmish.

However, this is not the case for me. First, here's the quest in my log:

[image: quest in log]

And here's what I see when I look at the available queues:

[image: queues list without skirmishes]

There's no skirmishes there at all, just 2 dungeons.

I've also tried talking to the NPC that alerted me to the skirmish, but he has no additional chat options.

I've also stood around for about 15 minutes near the place where the skirmish should be, but no dice. I've quested about in the area too, but never got a "call" for a skirmish, as far as I could tell.

How do you start the mentioned skirmish?

EDIT: Went back to "Penny the Apprentice", apparently I had missed her having a skirmish quest as well. However, after I accept the quest and then choose the dialogue option "View the Queue List", it just shows me the screen from the screenshot above, with zero queuing options for skirmishes...

Comment: Hmm, might've found an answer in [this announcement from 2019-10-10](https://www.arcgames.com/en/games/neverwinter/news/detail/11275373-queue-changes) but "low level skirmishes" should've been only removed from the _random_ queue according to the announcement...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done by soloing as a level 33 cleric. I went to the tower district and talked to the skirmish master, Aelgar the Fierce and chose to enter the Orc Assault with my current team (I wasn't in a group).

Comment: Thx for answering. Unfortunately I've uninstalled the game so I can't verify to accept, but your post might well contain defaults that help others landing here!